# What is the spatial status of Jeevatma according to Dwaitha Vedanta?

Tags: vedanta, dvaita

My information trading this comes exclusively from the lectures of Vidyavachaspathi Shri Bannanje Govindacharyaru.

In a lecture he said Dwaitha treats Jeevatma as an atom, that is Jeevatma is point like, dimensionless.
https://youtu.be/0qLZP56Tzks?t=750

But here he says that a Rishi divided his body into many body to exhaust his Prarabdha karma, which was quoted by Shri Madhwacharya.
https://youtu.be/NiIuuyW_IRo?t=1865

If Jeevatma is atom like, how was it spilt? Or in which body was the soul. If soul was in only one body, were the rest of the bodies soul less? Or if the soul is present in all the bodies then it had to be split, but even after being split how does the experiencer remain same? Different pieces of atma should experience differently, **if the experience is same then how is the experience connected?**

What is the spatial status of Jeevatma in Dwaitha?

Comment: yes different piece experience differently.. not the same.. the sum total of the experience of different piece need to be considered..in one of the stories brahma prays to Narayana and he sends different roopas to confluence of ganges with ocean along with all the devatahas for narayana to return to earth and eliminate daityas.. Naryana came and gave darshan. instead of immediately giving the word there itself.. to form of roopa of brahma, he asks every one to meet at the kailas where the moola roopa of brahma doing tapas.. in order give due credit to moola roopa

Comment: May what the above story is like we are watching football match in stadium and also in TV, but what is the difference.. difintely its same football match but experience are difference, May what level its same is it same in every aspect? that is question i do remember now one good well know example of splitting of jivas is Duryodhana, duryodhana was split into 101 piece, as each of his brothers killed all the jivas  went and joined back duryodhana, till last date duryodhana was not full till all his brothers were killed, then he puts of valiant fight with bhima with all his power otherwise he

Comment: would have run away.. but i havent have time to visit your link.. but there are many place jiva is split and experience karma..

Comment: i believe there is difference in jiva splitting and same soul in all aspects.. later should experience the reality in same level because its only one soul..

Comment: Here there is fundamental difference you are speaking about Paramatma..that is only soul and its same.. in all beings.. that is the same view in dvaitha vedanta.. we have jivatama along with paramatma.. that is unique that is not paramatma.. when you speak of soul in advaita you meant paramatma.. that is same experience should be same it should be all knowing.. your experience is known to paramatma.. than only he is sarvagna.. where as jivatma is unique that is not same..

Comment: Advaita denies existence jivatma only paramatma exists then this problem experience comes.. so he is questing the basic premize of one soul theory, there is only one soul that is there in all jiva.. only there ignorance make them different.. than if i eat you should feel boulted.. experience are different this proves existence of jivaatma.. that is what is conveyed by Madhvacharya.. here im not authority to quote from scripture based on my limited understanding.. this is what i can infere

Comment: you cannot apply same logic to jeevatma.. first jiva is apporna, dhosa ragitha, paramatma is poorna, sarvagna, sarvayapa, nirdhosa.. as per advaita one soul is encompassed with avidya.. i.e. paramatma made himself split into many and have avidya.. means ignorance why would in the world paramatma is ignorant.. or become ignorant.. there by becoming dosha ragitha.. that contradicts nirdoshathva of paramatma.. if you dont accept 2 entities present than everything irreconcilable or unresolved, this becomes Pandora box of questions..

Comment: I had answered you already regarding experience Sriman Madhvacharya question that advaitic prespective of paramatma i.e. soul who is ignorant due to avidya .. not about jivas.. here advaita speaks about paramatma as soul..

Comment: same soul experience should remain same.. yes why different.. they should experience same

Comment: for example you believe in demi god.. like saraswati, surya, and chandra and siva for manas, all this demi god should be present inside you for you to do karma, so siva is aware of what is happening in your manas, brahma is aware of what is happening in your buddhi.. even tough all the deities are present in their abode physically..

Comment: Krishna demonstrated it by eating one grain of leftover in amudhasurabhi filling dhrvasa stomach, but reverse cannot be possible.. dhurvasa is not present as vaisvarana in all peoples stomach.. that is question madhvacharya posses if somebody realized god then atleast this trick should be demonstrated..