# How can Dvaita explain splitting up of soul?

Tags: vedanta, advaita, adi-shankaracharya, dvaita, madhvacharya

I was researching Dvaita vs Advaita and came across [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/36042) really interesting question.

According to Dvaita, a person can split his soul and take multiple bodies and dissolve karma.

But how is this possible according to Dvaita? Please try to give references to scriptures of Dwaita school

If you split a single soul, isn't it two different souls, as it has two different karmic bodies? How can it be a single soul as now there are two atom like souls. The comment there says the two parts experience things differently. If there is only one consciousness in one soul, how can two souls experience differently? If there are two experiences then how can it be the same soul?

---

So the main question is do both pieces of soul have same experience or different experience.

**If you say same experience**, then you have to explain how , there is nothing connected from one to another soul so how can both souls have same experiences?

**So if you say they must have different experiences**, then Madhawacharya he himself says in [Upadhi Khandana](https://www.atmashrama.org/index.php?option=com_guru&view=gurutasks&catid=6&module=29-overview&cid=48-upadhi-khandana&tmpl=component&Itemid=0), that a single soul cannot experience things differently

> **Identity between Brahman and Jeeva is untenable**
>
> Acharya further refutes the identity by the following logic. If there
> were to be an identity of the Brahman with the Jeeva, then the all the
> sorrow of the Jeeva will have to be experienced by the Brahman as
> well. But it is well established that the Brahman does not experience
> any sorrow. This shows that they are two different entities and are
> not non-different. To this point, the Advaitin says that due to the
> Upadhi, the experiences will differ. For example, the hand does not
> experience the pain caused in the leg and vice versa. Why? This is due
> to the different Upadhi's like Hand and Leg. Though the body is one,
> it is because of the difference in the Upadhi that the experiences are
> different in different portions. In the same way, though there is
> identity, the Brahman and the Jeeva experience differently.
>
> **Difference in experience is due to different Upadhis**
>
> To his Acharya replies - it is not correct to say that the experience
> is shared only when there is no difference in the Upadhis. Though
> there is difference in the Upadhi's like hands and legs, the pain is
> experienced by the soul who is non-different. Because the experiencer
> is one, the pain in the leg or had is experienced by him only. In the
> same way, if there is identity between the Brahman and the Jeevas,
> then the experience should be same to both.

---

Note: The comment below the question addresses this using analogy of God, whose is antaryami and his soul is not in anu swaroopa or atom form. So any explanation must be done on the basis of jeevatmas, not on the example of God and different avatars existing at the same time etc.

Comment: It references the 'splitting' up into multiple bodies.........NOT multiple souls (jivas). YOU are a jiva with a body; you are not a body.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda yes but hiw can a single soul stay in multiple bodies?? As according to Dvaitis soul is anu swaroopa. So it has to be at two places at the same time. Now the two bodies will experience same or different?