# Source of Madhvacharya telling that a soul can be split

Tags: vedanta, dvaita, madhvacharya, madhwa

As I discuss the implications of [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/36042/27724) question [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/51778/27724),

The YouTube link given in the main question says it no more available

https://youtu.be/NiIuuyW_IRo?t=1865

Can any one give the source as to where exactly does Madhvacharya says that a soul can be split and karma can be solved separately?

Comment: The video is unavailable.

Comment: @hanugm That's what I said in the question.